# Append '/' after URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

How can I modify the above .htaccess rule to add a `/` after the URL but without mucking up the existing RewriteRule?

I tried simply appending: `RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]` but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a check if the URI ends with a /, and if not add one to whatever the URI was.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```